# Tags: is *gnome correct when referring to "the gnome 3 shell"?

Tags: discussion, tags

A user stated "*I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the gnome 3 shell* ", what would be the correct tag to use? As I read it *gnome refers to the **Standard Ubuntu**

Comment: Isn't it gnome-shell?. As I undesrtand gnome3 or gnome is the whole environment gnome-shell is just the shell.

Comment: I would have thought so, but that tag has not been used at all

Comment: Because  every new user calls Gnome Shell "Gnome 3", which is incorrect.

Comment: So I change it to gnome-shell, ok?

Comment: I believe that should be the correct tag for questions asking for Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu uses Unity instead of GNOME Shell. Both are GNOME. The GNOME Shell is the official shell for GNOME--Unity is Ubuntu's alternative shell.

For that reason, it would be misleading to use [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) to refer to an Ubuntu desktop with Unity, without also using it to refer to an Ubuntu desktop with GNOME Shell. GNOME Shell is officially part of GNOME. As far as the GNOME project is concerned, Unity is an unofficial replacement part for GNOME Shell.

Comment: hmmm... Your answer is very convincing - but how does that align with the description of *gnome ("the name for a collection of software that provides the desktop environment used by Ubuntu (but not Kubuntu or Xubuntu")?

Comment: @guntbert How *doesn't* this align with that description? An Ubuntu desktop *is* GNOME (just with one nonstandard component). A Kubuntu, Xubuntu, or Lubuntu desktop is not GNOME at all.

Comment: I am obviously confused - you said using *gnome for Ubuntu with unity would be misleading, but the description states exactly that (I don't want to seem nitpicking here, it is not that important :-))

Comment: @guntbert You don't seem nitpicking--this is important and valuable discussion/questions! And meta is exactly the right place for this! I'm not saying it's misleading to use [tag:gnome] to refer to an Ubuntu desktop with Unity. I'm saying it's misleading to use [tag:gnome] to refer to an Ubuntu desktop with Unity while also *excluding* Ubuntu desktops with GNOME Shell from being called/tagged [tag:gnome]. BTW, if you feel this meta question isn't fully answered, I recommend *unaccepting* this answer, so that other people know you're still looking for more discussion/answers.

Comment: Got it, thx for your patience, Eliah